# Android - storing two arrays in a single RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, android-recyclerview

I have two arrays :

```
private void InitData(){
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("element 1");
                    list.add("element 2");
                    list.add("element 3");
                    list.add("element 4");
                    list.add("element 5");
}
private void InitData2(){
    list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("item 1");
                    list.add("item 2");
                    list.add("item 3");
                    list.add("item 4");
                    list.add("item 5");
}
```

what I want to achieve is storing both lists in a singler RecyclerView in a way that the list with elements are shown on the left side of the screen and the items list are shown in the right side (like shown in the picture below)
I am now using two listviews and willing to convert to a single recyclerView
PS. preferably maintain the structure of the arrays

**EDIT / THIS IS THE TUTORIAL I AM GOING TO USE** [RecyclerView Tutorial](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-search-to-recyclerview-tutorial)

[image]

Comment: why not create your custom row for recycler view which will contain all those textviews?

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with? What have you already tried?

Comment: for the first comment from Vivek, I don't have an experience in daling with RecyclerViews and for the second comment from Egor I need the two arrays in one recyclerView like shown above

Comment: is there any kind of relationship between "elements" and "items"? I mean is it really meaningful to display this information together?

Comment: @Onheiron yes they are basically a translation (good morning (element) ....god morgen (item) )

Comment: In that case @Sohail answer is what you're looking for: you need to bind the original word and the translation together in an item object so they don't get mixed up, you should have them in a common object to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pojo class for this

```
public class DataHolder {

String item1,item2;

  public DataHolder(){

  }

  String getItem1(){
    retrun item1;
   }

   String getItem2(){
    retrun item2;
   }

  String setItem1(String item1){
    this.item1 = item1;
   }

 String setItem2(String item2){
    this.item2 = item2;
   }
}
```

then create DataHolder list.

```
ArrayList<DataHolder> bothItemDataList =new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
```

Add item like this.

```
DataHolder item = new DataHolder ();

item.setItem1("element 1");
item.setItem2("element 1");

bothItemDataList.add(item);
```

**Update Section:**

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public EditText search;
    //    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<DataHolder> list = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
    SimpleAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        countryList();  // in this method, Create a list of items.

        // call the adapter with argument list of items and context.
        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(list, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        addTextListener();

    }

    // this method is used to create list of items.
    public void countryList() {

        DataHolder item = new DataHolder();
        item.setName("Afghanistan");
        item.setTranslation("demo trans1");

        list.add(item);

        DataHolder item1 = new DataHolder();
        item1.setName("Paksitan");
        item1.setTranslation("my pakistan");

        list.add(item1);
//        list.add("Afghanistan");
//        list.add("Albania");
//        list.add("Algeria");
//        list.add("Bangladesh");
//        list.add("Belarus");
//        list.add("Canada");
//        list.add("Cape Verde");
//        list.add("Central African Republic");
//        list.add("Denmark");
//        list.add("Dominican Republic");
//        list.add("Egypt");
//        list.add("France");
//        list.add("Germany");
//        list.add("Hong Kong");
//        list.add("India");
//        list.add("Iceland");

    }


    public void addTextListener() {

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().toLowerCase();

                final List<DataHolder> filteredList = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = list.get(i).getName().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(query)) {

                        filteredList.add(list.get(i));
                    }
                }

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(filteredList, MainActivity.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // data set changed
            }
        });
    }
}

SimpleAdapter:

public class SimpleAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<DataHolder> list_item;
    public Context mcontext;


    public SimpleAdapter(List<DataHolder> list, Context context) {

        list_item = list;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    // Called when RecyclerView needs a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder of the given type to represent an item.
    @Override
    public SimpleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        // create a layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, null);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    // Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


        viewHolder.country_name.setText(list_item.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.country_translation.setText(list_item.get(position).getTranslation());

        viewHolder.country_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mcontext, list_item.get(position).getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    // initializes some private fields to be used by RecyclerView.
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView country_name, country_translation;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            country_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            country_translation = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.country_translation);

        }
    }

    //Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_item.size();
    }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.numetriclabz.androidsearch.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Sohail"
            android:textColor="#0b0080"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_translation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/country_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/country_name"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="#0b0080" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DataHolder:**

```
public class DataHolder {
    String name, translation;


    public DataHolder() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
 public void countryList() {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            DataHolder item = new DataHolder();
            item.setName(i + "name");
            item.setTranslation(i + "translation");

            list.add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question, please take time to check the dited part it will help you help me further

Comment: Thanks a lot ! exactly what I wanted, but do you have any idea how to push the second list further to the right

Comment: try your best if face some issue post an other question happy coding :)

Comment: excuse me but this process `DataHolder item = new DataHolder();
        item.setName("Afghanistan");
        item.setTranslation("demo trans1");

        list.add(item);

        DataHolder item1 = new DataHolder();
        item1.setName("Paksitan");
        item1.setTranslation("my pakistan");

        list.add(item1);` looks so time consuming and will get you bored after 4 or 5 items since I have more than 200 element in each list, is there another way out ??`

Comment: Use for loop dear

Comment: excuse my ignorance, can you put an example ?

Comment: M online from cell phone i will add it tomorrow morning.

Comment: so ?? Sohail Zahid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122173/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-sigvardr-olavrsson).